# Reliable way to check if the device is a phone, tablet, or set-top box

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application where I have to send statistics that has "STB/SMARTPHONE/TABLET" as one of the obligatory fields, and I can't quite find how to check that. I can't use screen size because of devices like Galaxy Note with huge screens, and some phones have higher resolution than some tablets, same with dpi (I think). Checking if screen width is larger than height is useless in my case because the app always runs in landscape. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What is your definition of what is a "SMARTPHONE" and what is a "TABLET"? Is it the ability to place phone calls?

Comment: @CommonsWare Basically, what the manufacturer calls it. If in price lists it's called "tablet", it's a tablet, and if it's a "phone", it's a smartphone. I know it's a stupid requirement, but I'm not the one who placed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically, what the manufacturer calls it.

You will need to make a list of every device manufacturer and contact them, asking them to declare for each of their device models whether it is a phone, tablet, etc.. You can then build a database that maps something like `Build.PRODUCT` to the manufacturer's declaration, and use that database to make the determination whether any given device is a phone, tablet, etc.

There is nothing in Android where a manufacturer declares whether the device is a mobile phone, tablet, set-top box, in-car navigation system, in-car entertainment system, watch, television, seat-back entertainment system (for airplanes), desktop phone, etc.

Comment: I was afraid it'd come to that. I'm so not looking forward to keeping tabs on all possible devices by Samsung, Sony, LG, HTC, and who knows what else *sigh* Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Kaworu: It may be simpler to get the requirement changed to something that can be measured more objectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should better send Manufacturer, Device, Android version, network and other related information back to statistics server. Leave the analytics at server side(new devices database update doesn't need client update)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not for me to decide. I'm not the one writing the product requirements. And all the things you've mentioned are also required fields, I just didn't mention them in the question because I have no problems there.